# Generating new column using conditions from multiple existing columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a column in a dataframe which depends on values in the current dataframe. This is the `head()` of the dataframe I'm starting with

EDIT: This is the dataframe I started with excluding unnecessary columns for the exercise. It has many other columns besides these two:

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Responded `Response Rate` 
  <chr>     <chr>                  
1 0%        0%                         
2 0%        0%                           
3 0%        0%                           
4 100%      100%                      
5 0%        0%                           
6 100%      0%
```

I want a new column called "Completion Rate" with values filled using the following criteria:

if `Responded` is `0%`, value should be `NA` (or `NULL` - whichever counts as no data in R)

else, take the value from `Response Rate`

i.e., the output should be:

```
 > head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Responded `Response Rate` `Completion Rate`
  <chr>     <chr>           <chr>            
1 0%        0%              NA               
2 0%        0%              NA               
3 0%        0%              NA               
4 100%      100%            100%             
5 0%        0%              NA               
6 100%      0%              0%
```

I tried creating the new column without any interim steps using `mutate` and `replace` with no joy. If someone could demonstrate how to do that, that would be great.

I then tried to build the `Completion Rate` by creating a column first:

```
df$"Completion Rate" <- df$`Response Rate`
```

and then replacing the values in this column where `NA` should be using this code:

```
df <- mutate(df, replace("Completion Rate", Responded == 0, NA, response_df$`Response Rate`))
```

The following error appeared:

```
> response_df <- mutate(response_df, replace("Completion Rate", Responded == 0, NA, response_df$`Response Rate`))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = replace("Completion Rate", Responded == 0, NA, response_df$`Response Rate`)`.
x unused argument (response_df$`Response Rate`)
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Running the extra suggested error checking code:

```
> rlang::last_error()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = replace("Completion Rate", Responded == 0, NA, response_df$`Response Rate`)`.
x unused argument (response_df$`Response Rate`)
Backtrace:
 1. dplyr::mutate(...)
 6. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 7. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))

> rlang::last_trace()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = replace("Completion Rate", Responded == 0, NA, response_df$`Response Rate`)`.
x unused argument (response_df$`Response Rate`)
Backtrace:
    x
 1. +-dplyr::mutate(...)
 2. +-dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
 3. | \-dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, ..., caller_env = caller_env())
 4. |   +-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 5. |   \-mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
 6. \-base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 7.   \-dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
<error/simpleError>
unused argument (response_df$`Response Rate`)
```

I tried using `0%` and `"0%"`. I tried referring to `Completion Rate` instead of `Response Rate` for the "else" argument of `replace`. I tried `= 0` instead of `== 0`. These gave different errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using dplyr from tidyverse

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Responded = c(0,0,0,100,0,100),
                 `Response Rate` = c(0,0,0,100,0,0))
print(df)
  Responded `Response Rate`
1         0             0
2         0             0
3         0             0
4       100           100
5         0             0
6       100             0


df <- df %>%
  mutate(`Completion Rate` <- ifelse(Responded==0, NA, `Response Rate`))

print(df)
  Responded `Response Rate` `Completion Rate`
1         0             0              NA
2         0             0              NA
3         0             0              NA
4       100           100             100
5         0             0              NA
6       100             0               0
```

or if you have values in string percentage

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Responded = c('0%','0%','0%','100%','0%','100%'),
                 `Response Rate` = c('0%','0%','0%','100%','0%','0%'))

print(df)
  Responded `Response Rate`
1        0%            0%
2        0%            0%
3        0%            0%
4      100%          100%
5        0%            0%
6      100%            0%

df <- df %>%
  mutate(`Completion Rate` = ifelse(Responded=='0%', NA, `Response Rate`))

Responded `Response Rate` `Completion Rate`
1        0%            0%            <NA>
2        0%            0%            <NA>
3        0%            0%            <NA>
4      100%          100%            100%
5        0%            0%            <NA>
6      100%            0%              0%
>
```

Comment: Thank you. My problem was not knowing to use backticks to refer to columns with spaces in the name

Answer (score 2):

Use `ifelse` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Completion_Rate = ifelse(Responded == '0%', NA, Response_Rate))

#  Responded Response_Rate Completion_Rate
#1        0%            0%            <NA>
#2        0%            0%            <NA>
#3        0%            0%            <NA>
#4      100%          100%            100%
#5        0%            0%            <NA>
#6      100%            0%              0%
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) -

```
df <- structure(list(Responded = c("0%", "0%", "0%", "100%", "0%", 
"100%"), Response_Rate = c("0%", "0%", "0%", "100%", "0%", "0%"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I tried something like this, but R disliked my attempts to refer to columns that have headings with spaces in. Your solution has used underscores to avoid spaces. How would I do it using the actual names of my columns? Everything in the new column is either NA or "Response Rate" when I try your code using the headings with spaces. Do I have to rename "Response Rate" to something without spaces first and then rename it again afterwards? Surely there is a way to refer to column headings that contain spaces in mutate with nested ifelse

Comment: To refer to column with spaces in them use backticks so use `\`Response Rate\``. It is recommended to have column name without spaces for the same reason.

Comment: That's really good to know. I'd always thought people were using apostrophes and that it was just an alternative to using quotation marks. That will save a lot of headaches down the line!